# PyQT5's input application dialogue box is not staying on windows 10 screen

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am developing a PyQt5 application which takes an input from the user in a string format and then utilise that variable further in the code.

**Problem:** The input box code when called from within a while loop (Ideally the box should stay and wait for the input from the user, thereby holding the while loop execution as well), instead it does not stay on the screen, it flashes and disappears in a fraction of seconds when executing the script on windows 10. But when I execute the code snippet mentioned below separately, then this type of problem does not appear.

**Code Snippet**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QLabel

def call_qt():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = QWidget()
    text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(gui, "User Input",
                """Do you wish to Continue [Y/N]?""")
    #print(text, ok)
    if ok:
        app.exit()
    else:
        app.exit()

    return text

print(call_qt())
```

I am not able to figure out, What could be the problem with this code snippet. Could you please help me with this? Also, I am new to PyQt5.

**Confusion**: The same problem does not exist on Ubuntu 18.

Comment: basically, not able to run the QT code twice in windows, seem like the app is flashing and disappearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this part is the process handling in windows. Do threading of the QT application and call this thread inside your while loop. This should solve the problem.

```
from queue import Queue
que = Queue()


def call_qt(out_que):
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QLabel
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = QWidget()
    text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(gui, "User Input",
                """Do you wish to Continue [Y/N]?""")
    #print(text, ok)
    if ok:
        app.exit()
    else:
        app.exit()

    out_que.put()


while True:
    t = Threading.thread(target=call_qt, args=(que,))
    t.start()
    t.join()
    print("text: ",que.get())
```

Answer (score 1):

same problem should happen on ubuntu. As you hit OK, application terminates itself and you wont be able to see output. Try this code, it prints the result on widget

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QVBoxLayout, QLabel)


def call_qt(main_widow):
    text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(main_widow, "User Input", "Do you wish to Continue [Y/N]?")
    return text, ok

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_widow = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    label = QLabel()
    layout.addWidget(label)
    main_widow.setLayout(layout)
    main_widow.show()
    text, ok = call_qt(main_widow)
    # if ok:
    #     sys.exit()
    label.setText(text)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I ran your snippet, it seems my question is not on point. Let me summarize it: I am not able to run the PyQt5 application twice, it seems the old process is still there. I tried 'app.exit()', 'sys.exit()' , 'del app'. But it still doesn't seem to work. I got the insights of my problem from here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2970